# Closing as duplicate but missing link to original

Tags: bug

Unclear what happened here but having [a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386696/the-brightness-on-my-iphone-is-changing-by-itself) closed as a duplicate without a link to the original looks like a bug to me.

[image]

Clicking on „Edit“ leads to an error page.

PS: Reopening and closing again will probably work, but keeping it like that for now in case it makes debugging easier.

Comment: [Related bug report on Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342366/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Not sure, the references only point to issues which happened *before* the new notices got introduced. The issue above happened yesterday. But anyway, I'll reopen and close again now, don't expect it to get fixed.